# Why '1' > 2 is false?

Tags: java, jsp, el

As, I think every programming language compares an `int` and a `char`on behave of `ASCII` value of `char`

I am new to java-Expression-Language. Now here, I have created a `.jsp` file in **`NETBEANS 5.5.1`**

**CODE:**

```
   <%=('1' > 2)?"true":"false"%>   //true
    ${('1' > 2)?"true":"false"}    //false
```

What is difference in these expressions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

EL has no notion of `char`. It's been treated as `String`. Single or double quotes, it doesn't matter, it's a `String`.

More detail about EL can be found in [EL 2.2 specification](http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/mrel/jsr245/index.html).

Comment: As per your deleted comment: The `<% %>` things are JSP *scriptlets*. It's basically "raw" Java code with the same rules as in a normal Java class. That's the difference with EL which has its own rules as you can read in the EL spec. Actually, *scriptlets* should be [avoided](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files) in JSP files.

Comment: +1 for giving link to your answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files

Answer (score 4):

There is no char literal type in JSP EL.  'a' defines a string containing the single letter a, rather than a java char.  The JSP EL evaluator then coerces the two sides to be the same so that they can actually be compared.  Numbers have higher precedence than strings, so '1' gets coerced to the integer 1 and then the comparison is done.